# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean Passing value to SP (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

while passing value to stored procedure getting error

```
"Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean".
```

not getting point why i am getting this issue while my code is,

C# code is here ,

```
invProject.targetprojectId =Convert.ToInt32(this.txtOrderNumber.Text);
        invProject.projects = this.txtProjectTitle.Text;
        invProject.bridge_cost = Convert.ToDouble(this.txtBridgeCost.Text);
        invProject.high_cost = Convert.ToDouble(this.txtHighwayCost.Text);
        invProject.bridge_comp = this.ddlbridgeComplexity.SelectedValue.ToString();
        invProject.hway_comp = this.ddlHighwayComplexity.SelectedValue.ToString();
        invProject.project_type = this.ddlProjectType.SelectedValue.ToString();
        invProject.proj_Owner = this.ddlProjectOwner.SelectedValue.ToString();
        invProject.ind_Exp = Convert.ToInt32(this.chkIndividualExperience.Checked);
```

Parameters that are passing are as follows,

```
 SqlParameter projectid = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Target_Project_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
           projectid.Value = InvPro.targetprojectId;

       SqlParameter title = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Projects", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       title.Value = InvPro.projects;
       SqlParameter bridgecost = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bridge_Cost", SqlDbType.Money);
       bridgecost.Value = InvPro.bridge_cost;
       SqlParameter highwaycost = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hway_Cost", SqlDbType.Money);
       highwaycost.Value = InvPro.high_cost;
       SqlParameter bComplexity = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bridge_Comp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       bComplexity.Value = InvPro.bridge_comp;
       SqlParameter hComplexity = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hway_Comp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       hComplexity.Value = InvPro.hway_comp;
       SqlParameter cProjectOwner = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       cProjectOwner.Value = InvPro.project_type;
       SqlParameter ProjectOwner = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Proj_Owner", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       ProjectOwner.Value = InvPro.proj_Owner;
       SqlParameter workclass = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Proj_WCB", SqlDbType.VarChar);
       workclass.Value = InvPro.proj_WCB;
       SqlParameter INdExp = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ind_Exp", SqlDbType.Bit);
       INdExp.Value = InvPro.proj_WCB;
```

SP define parameters are,

```
  @Target_Project_ID int,
      @Projects varchar(50),
      @Bridge_Cost money,
      @Hway_Cost money,
      @Bridge_Comp nvarchar(50),
      @Hway_Comp nvarchar(50),
      @ProjectType nvarchar(50),
      @Proj_Owner nvarchar(50),
      @Proj_WCB nvarchar(50),
      @Ind_Exp bit,
```

while column of table are ,

```
Target_Project_ID int
Projects  nvarchar
Bridge_Cost money
Hway_Cost money
Bridge_Comp  nvarchar
Hway_Comp  nvarchar
Proj_WCB  nvarchar
Proj_Owner  nvarchar
Ind_Exp     bit
```

i have tried alot but cant remove error hopes to listen from you soon

Thanks

Comment: what you are getting in `invProject.ind_Exp = Convert.ToInt32(this.chkIndividualExperience.Checked);`

Comment: chkIndividualExperience is check box we are getting 1 or 0 in it

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here :

```
   SqlParameter workclass = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Proj_WCB", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   workclass.Value = InvPro.proj_WCB;
   SqlParameter INdExp = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ind_Exp", SqlDbType.Bit);
   INdExp.Value = InvPro.proj_WCB;
```

You are setting the value of both parameters to the same object while they are of different Sqltypes. One is VarChar and the other is bit.

InvPro.proj_WCB can be either a String or a Boolean.
In your code you are treating it as if it is both.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value of the variable `InvPro.proj_WCB` to a boolean would be my guess.